# Audio latency OpenAL or RemoteIO Audio Unit

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

I have non-looping audio that I need to have as little latency as hardware-ically (technical term) possible on iPhone/iPod touch.  At an extreme, something that **smoothly** plays 10-20 samples in under a second, based on touches.

Who is king for this task?  OpenAL or Remote IO Audio Unit, and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RemoteIO is because it's the lowest level interface.

My buffer size is 512 frames, which at 44.1kHz is about 11ms.